# How to run a bash script and display any output in Conky?

Tags: bash, script, conky

The Bash script I’d like to run in [Conky](http://conky.sourceforge.net) is a loop so only needs to be run once. It’s a monitoring script in case my VoIP router goes down.

```
${execi 3600 /home/justin/pingvoip}
```

Conky doesn’t want to start with the above code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've worked around the problem by having the script output to a log file and I have conky tail the log file.

For anyone who wanted to see the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
rm /home/username/ping.log #deletes the log file when the script starts
downTime=0
lastAccessTime=$(date +"%s")
while [ true ]; do
if ! ping -c1 192.168.1.28 >& /dev/null; then
    downTime=$(( $(date +"%s") - $lastAccessTime ))
else
    downTime=0
    lastAccessTime=$(date +"%s")

fi

sleep 60

if [ $downTime -ge 60 ]; then
   notify-send -u normal "VoIP is down! Please Reboot." #displays a desktop notification
   mplayer -nolirc -really-quiet /home/username/chime.ogg #plays a sound
   echo "`date +%b%e,%l:%M%p` $1": "VoIP is down!" >>/home/username/ping.log #writes Date & text to the log file
fi


done
```

Answer (score 4):

The way to do this is through the conky command/variables such as `exec`,`execp`, `execi`, `pre_exec`,`execbar`, and `execgraph`.

Just like any other conky variable, only followed by bash -

```
${pre_exec ls -flah}
```

or

```
${exec your_script.sh}
```

Keep in mind that all of these - except for `execi` and `pre_exec` will run every time conky 'ticks' - which can be very resource consuming, depending on your script.

See the complete list and more information in the [list of Conky objects](http://conky.sourceforge.net/variables.html):

Comment: you can also specify the execution interval by using:
`execi <seconds> your_script.sh`